# Shortest distance between two affine subspaces through orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, orthogonality, projection, affine-geometry

I'm trying to show the following:

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional euclidean vector space, with two vector subspaces $S_1 \subset V$ and $S_2 \subset V$. Suppose that $X, Y$ are affine subspaces with $X = x + S_1$ and $Y = y + S_2$, that $P_U$ is the orthogonal projection onto a vector subspace $U$, and finally that
> $$
> d(X, Y) = \min \{d(x,y) \mid x \in X,\, y \in Y\}.
> $$
>
> Show that the following is true:
> $$
> d(X, Y) = \lVert P_{S_1 + S_2}(x - y) + y - x \rVert. 
> $$

I've learned and used a similar formula before:
$$
d(v, U) = \inf\{\lVert v - u \rVert\ \mid u \in U\} 
= \lVert P_{U^{\perp}}(v) \rVert 
$$
with $U$ being a vector subspace of the vector space $V$. In this case there was also the condition that $V = U \oplus U^{\perp}$. I guess my problem is that I can understand the orthogonal projection visually if I project a vector onto, for example, a plane, but I can't understand the projection onto two subspaces.

**Edit:** Thank you @Stéphane Jaouen for the picture, it was invaluable when trying to come up with some sort of proof.

Regarding the proof, I have the following so far:

$$
d(X,Y) = \| x - y \|
$$
The definition of $d(X,Y)$ is the norm of the two vectors $x \in X$, $y \in Y$. Both these vectors are at the same time in our vector space, i.e. $x, y \in V$.

With the Pythagoras' theorem we get
$$
\| x - y \|^2 = \| P_{S_1 + S_2}(x - y) \|^2 + \| s^{\perp} \|^2
$$
with $s^{\perp}$ being a vector orthogonal to $S_1 + S_2$. (In Stéphane's picture this would be $\vec{PV}$). Rearrange this equation to get
$$
\| s^{\perp} \|^2 = \| x - y \|^2 - \| P_{S_1 + S_2}(x - y) \|^2
$$
Therefore the shortest distance between $X$ and $Y$ is
$$
\begin{align*}
d(X,Y) &= \| x - y \| \\
&= \| s^{\perp} \| \\
&= \| s^{\perp} \| \\
&= \| (x - y) - P_{S_1 + S_2}(x - y)\|
\end{align*}
$$
If we look at $(x - y)$ and $P_{S_1 + S_2}(x - y)$ as vectors, the distance will be the same if we change the direction of the vector and we can rewrite this as
$$
\begin{align*}
&= \| P_{S_1 + S_2}(x - y) - (x - y)\| \\
&= \| P_{S_1 + S_2}(x - y) - x + y\| \\
&= \| P_{S_1 + S_2}(x - y) + y - x\| \\
\end{align*}
$$

I'm not really sure whether I can just transfer the result of Pythagoras' theorem into my equation, however.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, what do you mean by "projection onto two subspaces"? According your definition $P_{S_1+S_2}$ is the orthogonal projection onto the subspace $S_1 + S_2$. This is a single subspace spanned by, e.g., the union of spanning sets of $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is a very good correction of my faulty thinking.

I did a practical example with the formula that I have to prove and while doing it I also treated $S_1 + S_2$ as one subspace by building an orthonormal basis via Gram-Schmidt process out of the vectors from both $S1$ and $S2$.

Comment: Perhaps you’ve already done this, but you might draw a picture in $\Bbb R^3$ with $X$ and $Y$ lines and see exactly what's going on with this formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before we go any further, I think it's helpful to follow the advice of @Ted Shifrin.

$ x,y \in \mathbb R^3; \color{green}{S_1}, \color{red}{S_2}$ two vector lines; $S_1\oplus S_2$ is represented in $\color{grey}{\text{grey}}$; $P:=P_{\color{grey}{S_1\oplus S_2}}(x-y)$; $V:=x-y=\vec{OP}+\vec{PV}$; $\vec{OP}=\color{green}{\vec{OP_1}}+\color{red}{\vec{OP_2}}; x_1:=x-\color{green}{P_1}; y_1:=y+\color{red}{P_2};\color{Green} {X}:=x+\color{DarkGreen} {S_1}; \color{Orange} {Y}:=y+\color{red} {S_2}$
[image]
$$d(\color{green}X,\color{orange}Y)=||x_1-y_1||=||\vec{PV}||=\lVert x-y-P_{S_1 + S_2}(x - y)  \rVert$$

---

Regarding the proof, you have $$\forall \xi\in X=x_1+S_1, \forall \eta \in Y=y_1+S_2$$ $$\xi=x_1+u_1, \eta=y_1+u_2$$with $u_i\in S_i(i=1,2)\subset S_1+S_2$

Then $||\xi-\eta||^2=||x_1-y_1||^2+||u_1+u_2||^2$(Pythagora's theorem)

So $||\xi-\eta||^2\geq ||x_1-y_1||^2$ and finally $$||\xi-\eta||\geq||x_1-y_1||$$

So, $$d(X,Y)=||x_1-y_1||=||\vec{PV}||=\lVert x-y-P_{S_1 + S_2}(x - y)  \rVert.\square$$