# Difficult Vectors Problem (Calculus & Vectors)

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis, 3d

Find parametric equations of a line that intersects line 1 and line 2 at right angles.

Line 1: $[x,y,z] = [4,8,-1] + t[2,3,-4]$ and

Line 2: $[x,y,z] = [7,2,-1] + k[-6,1,2]$.

I've tried solving this problem by crossing the direction vectors to get the direction of the normal, but I don't know how to find a point on the normal to get the overall equation of it. I originally thought I could just find the point of intersection of the 2 lines to get the intersection point, but the 2 lines turned out to be skew. Please help.

Comment: Hint: Write the equation of the vector between points on both lines as a function of $t$ and $k$, then use the dot product to determine what values of $t$ and $k$ make this vector orthogonal to both lines.

Comment: Line $1$ is of the shape $P+tV$, parametrized by $t\in \Bbb R$, where $P$ is a given point on the line, and $V$ is a choice of "direction" for it. Similarly, line $2$ has a parametrization as $Q+kW$, here $k\in\Bbb R$ is the parameter. Now draw the plane through line $1$ parallel to line $2$. It is parametrized by $P+tV+kW$. The searched line is perpendicular on this plane, so a possible choice of a direction is $U=V\times W$. Compute this vector product $U$, and consider now the plane through line $1$ which also goes in the direction $U$, cut it with line $2$...

Answer (score 0):

This question relates to a particular case of a general case that is dealt with [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4879119/shortest-distance-between-two-affine-subspaces-through-orthogonal-projection/4880354#4880354) for example.
[image]

Let $\color {grey}{\mathcal P}=\mathbb R \color {green}{(2,3,-4)}\oplus \mathbb R \color{red}{(-6,1,2)}, X=(4,8,-1), Y=(7,2,-1)$ $$(2,3,-4)\times (-6,1,2)=(10,20,20)=10(1,2,2)\text{(cross product)}$$

The numbers offered are well chosen to avoid excessively complicated calculations. We obtain $$X-Y=(4,8,-1)-(7,2,-1)=(-3,6,0)=\color{green}{(+1)}(2,3,-4)+(-6,1,2)+(1,2,2)$$
So, In accordance with [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4879119/shortest-distance-between-two-affine-subspaces-through-orthogonal-projection/4880354#4880354), we have with the notations in the figure$$x_1=X\color{green}{-1}(2,3,-4)=(2,5,3)$$

And parametric equation of the line $l $ that intersects line 1 and line 2 at right angles is $$\boxed{l:(2,5,3)+t(1,2,2), t\in \mathbb R}$$

---

In addition, we have $$y_1=Y+(-6,1,2)=(1,3,1)$$ And we check that $$x_1-y_1=1.(1,2,2)$$