# How to find the number of possible planes equidistant from $5$ points $3$ of which are collinear.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, contest-math, 3d

$\vec a,\vec b,\vec c,\vec d$ are four non zero vectors and points $P(\vec a), \; Q(\vec a+\vec b+\vec c), \; R(\vec a-\vec b-\vec c), \; S(\vec d),\; T(\vec a +\vec d)$ are distinct points such that T does not lie in the plane of P,Q and S. Find the number of planes equidistant from all the points $P,Q,R,S,T$.

---

Any three vectors are coplaner, now $P,Q,R$ are collinear as, $\vec{OR}=\dfrac{2\vec{OP}-\vec{OQ}}{ 2-1}$. So any plane parallel to this line will be equidistant from $P,Q,R$. But I think that points $S,T$ may be aligned in space such that we get no plane which is equidistant from all five points. But answer is given *$3$     planes are possible*. Can not visualise  at this stage. Please help.

Comment: Hint: project everything onto the plane perpendicular to the line which contains the three points.

Comment: Collinear has two  letters L. I don't know why either.

Comment: As suggested I am considering 3 parallel plane $\perp$ to the line $PQR$ each seperated by some distance; one containing Origin $(0,0)$ , 2nd $\vec S$ and 3rd $\vec T$. What to do now ? Need some more guidance.

Comment: Project everything onto one single plane, not three different planes.

For a visual intuition, you can imagine yourself looking directly in the direction of the line $PQR$ (with an orthogonal camera). Each plane parallel to that line will appear as a line. The three collinear points will just appear as a single point, so the 5 points will appear to be just 3. Thus the problem reduces to counting the number of lines equidistant from three points in 2D space

Comment: Getting your point. Now there are $3$ lines possible equidistant from three points in 2d space, each bisecting one of three altitudes of the triangle formed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Skdmg : With a little more experience, you'll write $a,b,c,d,P=a,Q=a+b+c,R=a-b-c, R=2P-Q$; which is much simpler to handle. You can think of them either as points or as vectors; It's up to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P,Q,R$ are collinear. Let $d=PQ$, with $R\in d $. Then there are $3$ cases to consider :

- Let $\mathcal P$ the plane containing $d$ and $S$, $S'$ the orthogonal projection of $S$ on  $\mathcal P$, $I$ the midpoint of $SS'$ and $\mathcal P_1$ the plane parallel to $\mathcal P$ passing through $I $;
- Let $\mathcal Q$ the plane containing $d$ and $T$, $T'$ the orthogonal projection of $T$ on  $\mathcal Q$, $J$ the midpoint of $TT'$ and $\mathcal P_2$ the plane parallel to $\mathcal Q$ passing through $J $;
- Let $e:=ST$ and $K$ the midpoint of the common perpendicular to $d$ and $e$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4879119/shortest-distance-between-two-affine-subspaces-through-orthogonal-projection/4880354#4880354) for example) and let $\mathcal P_3$ the plane passing throug $K$, whose direction is the one spaned by that of $d$ and $e$.

$\mathcal P_1,\mathcal P_2,\mathcal P_3$ are the $3$ planes.